# Cannot authenticate in Google OAuth2.0 for server to server applications

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up the Google OAuth authentication so I could get an access token for an account service and I could use other services through REST API such as Cloud Storage.
Problem is that I get an 400 error when I make the access token request and the message is generic so I can't know what's not working.
I'm using Typescript, Node, and some packages such as jsonwebtokens or jwt-simple for signing the JWT.

Any ideas if I'm missing something?

```
import moment from 'moment';
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken'; // try wuth this one for signing the JWT too but same result
import axios from 'axios';
import base64Url from 'base64url';

export const authentication = function (): void {
    const nowInUnix = moment().unix();
    const secret = 'MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCc9HWEZ2VtoIt5...........';
    //this's supposed to be my private key so I removed the beginning and end from it 'cause in the file from where i get it was like this: "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----MY_KEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

    let header = { "alg": "RS256", "typ": "JWT" };
    const headerEncoded = base64Url.encode(JSON.stringify(header));
    let claims = {
        "iss": "service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
        "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "exp": nowInUnix + 2000,
        "iat": nowInUnix
    };
    const claimsEncoded = base64Url.encode(JSON.stringify(claims));
    // console.log(claimsEncoded);
    const stringToEncrypt = headerEncoded + '.' + claimsEncoded;
    // console.log(stringToEncrypt);
    const signature = jwt.encode(stringToEncrypt, secret);
    // console.log(signature);
    const fullToken = headerEncoded + '.' + claimsEncoded + '.' + signature;
    console.log(fullToken);

    // Something else i don't know if how to pass the params, I assumed it's like query params but I also tried sending the in the body request and same result.
    axios.post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=${fullToken}`)
        .then(res => console.log('todo ok'))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

This is the error I get:
BAD_REQUEST: 400
[screenshot of the error i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yPhi.png)

Google Docs I read: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects

Comment: 1)  you are generating the wrong signature type (HS256). Use RS256 `jwt.encode(payload, secret, 'RS512')`. 2) The function `jwt.encode` returns the entire token (header, payload, and signature) and not only the signature. 3) Do not strip the Private Key. 4) Once you have the Signed JWT, you must exchange for an Access Token. Read this article for how: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I changed the code based on your comment and it finally worked. I used jsonwebtoken package for encoding with the RS512. I only passed the ```claims```object to the signing method and included all the private key string, and it's working perfect now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the code based on the first comment, and now it's working like this:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import jsonwebtoken from 'jsonwebtoken';
import axios from 'axios';

export const authentication = function (): void {
    const nowInUnix = moment().unix();
    const secret = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----YOUR_KEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    let claims = {
        "iss": "service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control",
        "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "exp": nowInUnix + 3600,
        "iat": nowInUnix
    };
    const token = jsonwebtoken.sign(claims, secret, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
    const response: any = await axios.post(`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=${token}`)
        .catch(e => console.log('Error occured: \n' + e));
    console.log(response.data);
}
```

response:

```
{
  access_token: 'MY_TOKEN',
  expires_in: 3599,
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
```